# How to distinguish between which class calls a method?

Tags: java, class

I'm trying to determine which class has called a method, is there a more elegant way to do this?

```
public void testMethod(Class c) {
    String className = c.getCanonicalName();
    int splitAfter = className.lastIndexOf(".");
    String parsedName = className.substring(splitAfter + 1,className.length());

    if (parsedName.contains("ClassA")) {
    // Do class A specific stuff
    } else if (parsedName.contains("ClassB")) {
    // Do class B specific stuff
    } else if (parsedName.contains("ClassC")) {
    // Do Class C specific stuff
    }
}
```

Called with

```
testMethod(this.getClass)
```

Comment: Why would you want to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you can't do:

```
if(c == ClassA.class) {
    // do stuff
} else if(c == ClassB.class) {
    // do stuff
} else if(c == ClassC.class) {
    // do stuff
}
```

?

No string manipulation required!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can get the caller class from the stack trace:

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
```

It is a stack, so the previous Class should be at index 1.

See [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html) for more info on `StackTraceElement`.